# jOOQ code generation: issues with `ForeignKey` if the same table is referenced multiple times

Tags: sqlite, jooq

I have used jOOQ 3.14.16 to generate tables, records, and pojos from an existing SQLite database.
Recently we have upgraded to 3.18.6 and I have rerun the code generation.

The code generated with the newer version causes issues with `ForeignKey` if the same table is referenced multiple times. While jOOQ 3.14.16 generated multiple `ForeignKey`s as expected, the newer version has generated only one `ForeignKey`.

jOOQ 3.14.16:

```
public static final ForeignKey<DataRecord, TextIdentifierRecord> FK___DATA___TEXT_IDENTIFIER__1 = Internal.createForeignKey(Data.DATA, DSL.name("fk_Data_TextIdentifier_1"), new TableField[] { Data.DATA.TOPIC_ID }, Keys.PK___TEXT_IDENTIFIER, new TableField[] { TextIdentifier.TEXT_IDENTIFIER.TEXT_IDENTIFIER_ID }, true);
public static final ForeignKey<DataRecord, TextIdentifierRecord> FK___DATA___TEXT_IDENTIFIER__2 = Internal.createForeignKey(Data.DATA, DSL.name("fk_Data_TextIdentifier_2"), new TableField[] { Data.DATA.CORRECTED_LABEL_ID }, Keys.PK___TEXT_IDENTIFIER, new TableField[] { TextIdentifier.TEXT_IDENTIFIER.TEXT_IDENTIFIER_ID }, true);
    public static final ForeignKey<DataRecord, TextIdentifierRecord> FK___DATA___TEXT_IDENTIFIER__3 = Internal.createForeignKey(Data.DATA, DSL.name("fk_Data_TextIdentifier_3"), new TableField[] { Data.DATA.LABEL_ID }, Keys.PK___TEXT_IDENTIFIER, new TableField[] { TextIdentifier.TEXT_IDENTIFIER.TEXT_IDENTIFIER_ID }, true);
```

jOOQ 3.18.6:

```
public static final ForeignKey<DataRecord, TextIdentifierRecord> FK___DATA__PK___TEXT_IDENTIFIER = Internal.createForeignKey(Data.DATA, DSL.name("fk_Data_pk_TextIdentifier"), new TableField[] { Data.DATA.TOPIC_ID, Data.DATA.CORRECTED_LABEL_ID, Data.DATA.LABEL_ID }, Keys.PK___TEXT_IDENTIFIER, new TableField[] { TextIdentifier.TEXT_IDENTIFIER.TEXT_IDENTIFIER_ID, TextIdentifier.TEXT_IDENTIFIER.TEXT_IDENTIFIER_ID, TextIdentifier.TEXT_IDENTIFIER.TEXT_IDENTIFIER_ID }, true);
```

Is there any possibility to get the old behavior with the newer jOOQ version?

**Edit:**

Table creation:

```
CREATE TABLE "TextIdentifier" (
  "textIdentifierId" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ,
  "text" TEXT NOT NULL
) STRICT
```

```
CREATE TABLE "Data" (
  "dataId" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  "labelId" INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES "TextIdentifier"("textIdentifierId"),
  "correctedLabelId" INTEGER NULL REFERENCES "TextIdentifier"("textIdentifierId"), 
  "topicId" INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES "TextIdentifier"("textIdentifierId")) STRICT
```

Comment: Would you mind sharing the complete `CREATE TABLE` of the involved tables to help reproduce the issue

Comment: i have just tried to reproduce the case and all work great. Can you one more time try to regenerate the classes ?  jooq.version = 3.18.6.